Issue with Wedge Texture Coordinates in VCG Mesh Library when Importing OBJ File
I am attempting to read an OBJ file with texture coordinates using the VCG library in C++. Here's the code snippet I am working with:
std::string DelaudeyMeshWithTexture =
                "E:/Learn_MeshLab/meshlab/build/data/DelauneyWithTexture.obj";
CMeshO delaunayMesh;
int mask = vcg::tri::io::Mask::IOM_VERTTEXCOORD | vcg::tri::io::Mask::IOM_WEDGTEXCOORD;

int result = vcg::tri::io::ImporterOBJ<CMeshO>::Open(delaunayMesh, DelaudeyMeshWithTexture.c_str(), mask);

delaunayMesh.face.EnableWedgeTexCoord();

if (!(mask & vcg::tri::io::Mask::IOM_WEDGTEXCOORD)) {
    std::cerr << "Warning: Delaunay mesh does not have wedge texture coordinates." << std::endl;
}

for (const auto& face : delaunayMesh.face) {
    if (!face.IsD()) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            const auto& texCoord = face.WT(j);
            qDebug() << texCoord.U() << "," << texCoord.V();
        }
    }
}

However, when I run the code, I keep getting this warning:
Warning: Delaunay mesh does not have wedge texture coordinates.

And the output is always:
0.5 , 0.5
0.5 , 0.5
0.5 , 0.5
...ALL 0.5

I also tried setting the mask to 0, but that didn't work either.
Why is VCG not reading the wedge texture coordinates correctly, and how can I fix this?

Repeating my comment from the staging ground: You should run your code in a debugger and carefully step through the Open call. From a quick browse it looks like IOM_WEDGTEXCOORD is set as soon as a single texture coordinate is present in the obj file, but then a later call to Mask::ClampMask checks whether the face type associated with CMeshO has wedge texture coordinates. (whatever those may be) Edit your question with the definition of CMeshO so people can reproduce your issue.

hey! I solved it ,look my answer in this issue@Botje

I just solved this issue. I found that after adding this line, delaunayMesh.face.EnableWedgeTexCoord();, and modifying the output format for the face texture coordinates as follows:
for (auto& face : delaunayMesh.face) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // Get the texture coordinates of the current vertex
        Point2f texCoord = face.WT(i).P();

        qDebug()
            << "Vertex texture coordinates: " << texCoord.X() << ", " << texCoord.Y();
    }
}

my coordinates started loading correctly. I still don’t fully understand the difference between face.WT(i).P() and my original definition, but at least the issue is now resolved.
